# How to move a post in Vacancies so it appears in News/Events?

Tags: plugins, user-interface

I've just taken over managing a website for an organisation and I'm trying to manage a Vacancies listing so that it also appears in the News/Events section. The problem is on my Wordpress CMS for some reason Vacancies and all other posts (including those that belong to News/Events) are listed separately (see below):

[image: vacancies vs posts]

I can add a Post to any menu on the site using the right sidebar

[image]

But when I try to do the same for posts that appear in Vacancies that menu option doesn't appear in the right sidebar (I only get the 'Job Types' option below)

[image]

Please does anyone know how to sort this out (or identify the plugin that organises the site UX)? Realise this is somewhat a noob question, but as I can't find an installed plugin that manages Job Vacancies I'm not sure how to edit settings and move the vacancy to appear in the News/Events section. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is basic WP functionality, it's not dependent on a plugin.

You need to locate where the vacancies post type is registered and add the `category` taxonomy to the `taxonomies` argument:

```
'taxonomies'    => [ `(your job type tax and any others)`, 'category' ],
```

This should get the categories meta box onto your post type's edit sidebar. However, it's quite possible that there are other factors controlling what's output to your archive pages.